# Delete a branch in Binary tree( Linked List implementation)

Tags: python, data-structures, binary-tree

I am trying to create a binary tree using a linked list. I want to delete a node in a binary tree, the way I implemented is to set the address(pointer) to the branch that I want to delete as None, but when I run the traversal methods, the branch still shows up.

here is my code

```
class tree:
  def __init__(self,val):
    self.val=val
    self.left=None
    self.right=None
 
  def preorder(root):
    if root is None:
      return 
    print(root.val)
    tree.preorder(root.left)
    tree.preorder(root.right)
  
  
  def inorder(root):
    if root is None:
      return
    tree.inorder(root.left)
    print(root.val)
    tree.inorder(root.right)
  
  def postorder(root):
    if root is None:
      return
    tree.postorder(root.left)
    tree.postorder(root.right)
    print(root.val)

  def levelorder(root):
    if root is None:
      return
    Q=[]
    Q.append(root)

    while Q!=[]:
      l=len(Q)
      for i in range(l):
        print(Q[i].val)

      temp=[]
      for i in Q:
        if i.left is not None:
          temp.append(i.left)
        if i.right is not None:
          temp.append(i.right) 
      Q.clear()
      Q=temp.copy()

  def search(root,value):
    o=[]
    o.append(tree.levelorder(root))
    if value in o:
      return "Found"
    else:
      return "Not Found"

  def insert(root,value,where):
    if root is None:
      return
    Q=[]
    Q.append(root)
    value=tree(value)
    while Q!=[]:
      for i in Q:
        if i.val==where:
          if i.left is not None:
            i.right=value
          else:
            i.left=value
          return

      temp=[]
      for i in Q:
        if i.left is not None:
          temp.append(i.left)
        if i.right is not None:
          temp.append(i.right) 
      Q.clear()
      Q=temp.copy()
    
  def delete(root,value):
    if root is None:
      return
    Q=[]
    Q.append(root)
    value=tree(value)
    while Q!=[]:
      for i in Q:
        if i.left is not None and i.left.val==value:
          i.left.val=None
          i.left=None
        if i.right is not None and i.right.val==value:
          i.right.val=None
          i.right=None
        return
          
      temp=[]
      for i in Q:
        if i.left is not None:
          temp.append(i.left)
        if i.right is not None:
          temp.append(i.right) 
      Q.clear()
      Q=temp.copy()
```

and here is how I created the tree

```
base=tree("drinks")
L=tree("hot")
R=tree("cold")
LL=tree("coffe")
LR=tree("tea")
LRL=tree("w milk")
LRR=tree("wo milk")

base.left=L
base.right=R
L.left=LL
L.right=LR
LR.left=LRL
LR.right=LRR
```

Now when I run the delete method, the object that is supposed to be deleted still shows up.

```
tree.delete(base,"w milk")
tree.levelorder(base)
drinks
hot
cold
coffe
tea
ice cream
w milk
wo milk <=== the node i am trying to delete
```

Comment: Is it correct that you compare `tree(value)` with `.val` property? I'm not good at Python, but seems like you're comparing a pointer to the node with a string

Comment: You are also immediately returning out of the `while` loop. The algorithm for deletion is quite different. Even if it would work, you would not only delete the found node, but also all nodes below it (children, descendants)

Comment: @E. Shcherbo  I removed that line '''value=tree(value)''' it was a mistake, but still, it does not delete the node

Comment: As @trincot noticed you're returning immediately from your `for` and `while` loop, you probably want to return only after you've removed the value, but now it seems you return in the first iteration after you compare left and right children of the root

Comment: @trincot yes I created the delete method to delete the entire branch, along with the child descendants. what would be the right way to delete the branch

Comment: @E.Shcherbo got it. Thanks, simple mistake I didn't notice

Answer (score 1):

The main issues:

- `delete` method's `while` loop will exit immediately, because of the `return` statement
- The value to compare with should not be turned into a node with `value=tree(value)`

Some remarks on your code:

- You'll not be able to ever delete the root node of the tree, since you only check the values of *child* nodes. In order to allow the root to be deleted, and to represent an empty tree, you should really consider creating a second class. The current class could then be renamed to `Node` and the new class could become `Tree`.
- It is a common habit to use a capital first letter for class names, while for variable names you would always start with a lower case letter. So not `Q`, but `q`.
- It is not such good practice to print inside methods of such classes: these methods should just provide tools to iterate over nodes, but they should not print them. Use `yield` instead.

  For instance, `search` should return the *node* when it is found and `None` otherwise. Don't print the result.
- The `insert` method may actually delete node(s) when both the left and right child of the `where` node are already occupied. It would be better to reject such an insert.
- In the OOP pattern, it is widely accepted to call the first argument of instance methods `self`. In OOP, you would call these methods with the dot notation: so instead of `tree.postorder(root.left)` you would do `root.left.postorder()`.
- You have quite some code repetition: mainly for traversals, and where you use the queue algorithm twice. Try to avoid that.

Here is how you could modify your code to align to these suggestions:

```
class Node:
    def __init__(self, val):
        self.val = val
        self.left = None
        self.right = None
    
    def traverse(self, kind=0, parent=None):
        if kind == 0:  # pre-order
            yield (self, parent)  # don't print in methods
        if self.left:
            yield from self.left.traverse(kind, self)
        if kind == 1:  # in-order
            yield (self, parent)
        if self.right:
            yield from self.right.traverse(kind, self)
        if kind == 2:  # post-order
            yield (self, parent)
  
class Tree:
    def __init__(self):
        self.root = None  # Representing an empty tree

    def traversevalues(self, kind=0):
        if self.root:
            for node, parent in self.root.traverse(kind):
                yield node.val

    def preorder(self):
        yield from self.traversevalues(0)

    def inorder(self):
        yield from self.traversevalues(1)
  
    def postorder(self):
        yield from self.traversevalues(2)
  
    def levelorder(self):
        if self.root:
            q = [self.root]
            while q:
                temp = []
                for node in q:
                    yield node.val
                    if node.left:
                        temp.append(node.left)
                    if node.right:
                        temp.append(node.right) 
                q = temp

    def search(self, value):
        if self.root:
            return next((edge for edge in self.root.traverse() if edge[0].val == value), None)

    def insert(self, value, where=None):
        if not where:
            if self.root:
                raise ValueError("Must call insert with second argument")
            else:
                self.root = Node(value)
        else:
            edge = self.search(where)
            if edge:
                parent = edge[0]
                if not parent.left:
                    parent.left = Node(value)
                elif not parent.right:
                    parent.right = Node(value)
                else:
                    raise ValueError(f"Node {where} already has 2 children")
            else:
                raise ValueError(f"Node {where} not found")
    
    def deletesubtree(self, value):
        edge = self.search(value)
        if edge:
            node, parent = edge
            if parent.left == node:
                parent.left = None
            else:
                parent.right = None
        else:
            raise ValueError(f"Node {value} not found")

tree = Tree()
tree.insert("drinks")
tree.insert("hot", "drinks")
tree.insert("cold", "drinks")
tree.insert("coffee", "hot")
tree.insert("tea", "hot")
tree.insert("with milk", "tea")
tree.insert("without milk", "tea")
print(*tree.levelorder())
tree.deletesubtree("without milk")
print(*tree.levelorder())
```

Comment: Thank you for the remarks and explanation. I am still a beginner and don't understand a lot of it. I'll try to  implement it and understand it and get back when I don't understand something